# Какие минусы в хранении пароля в cookie для авторизации?

Tags: php, mysql, cookie

Можно ли хранить в куках логин/пароль и при подключении к сайту их сверять? Во всех примерах, которые я встречал, вместо пароля сохраняется зашифрованный ключ, который генерируется по время авторизации. Насколько это безопаснее хранения пароля напрямую?

Comment: зачем вообще в куках хранить логин и тем более пароль? данные авторизации хранятся в сессии на стороне сервера, в куках хранится ключ сессии обычно, не более.

Comment: а как по другому можно запомнить пользователя на сайте?

Comment: [PHP Сессии](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php)

Comment: Я неправильно задал вопрос. Мне нужно, чтобы эти данные хранились долгое время. Для этого тоже нужно использовать сессии?

Comment: Для долгого времени есть сессии и БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Куки передаются при всех запросах. 
Если кто-то перехватит/просмотрит cookie с паролем, то пароль пользователя будет скомпрометирован.